# How to use one activity indicator in several views?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

i have a class SpinnerController that have method for activity indicator

```
-(void)StartSpinner
 {

   [spinner startAnimating];

  spinner.hidden=YES;

      spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(141.0, 190.0,  

      80.0, 80.0)];

       [self.view addSubview:spinner];
     NSLog(@"Spinner running");
    }

   -(void)StopSpinner
   {

    [spinner stopAnimating];

  spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(141.0, 190.0, 80.0, 

    80.0)];

   [self.view addSubview:spinner];

     }
```

i have 8 other viewControllers , i want to use activity indicator using above functions .

how can i do this ?

Comment: add this functions to every other view controller.. is it not simple?

Comment: i want to use this function from one class to another classes .

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shared instance of activity indicator. It will help you to create single instance and manage throughout the code. You can refer [MBProgressHUD](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mbprogresshud) code.

Answer (score 1):

Two things will help make your code better.

First, lazily instantiate the `UIActivityIndicatorView`. I like to prefix private ivars with an underscore, but that's not required.

```
-(UIActivityIndicatorView *) spinner
{
    if (_spinner == nil)
    {
       _spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(141.0, 190.0, 80.0, 80.0)];
       _spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
       [self.view addSubview:_spinner];
    }
    return _spinner;
}
```

Now you can use `[self spinner]` to always refer to the same object reference.

```
-(void)StartSpinner
{
    [[self spinner] startAnimating];
}
-(void)StopSpinner
{
    [[self spinner] stopAnimating];
}
```

Now you can just create your other view controllers as subclasses of `SpinnerController` to inherit the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the methods public by using

```
+(void)StartSpinner
{
    ....
}
```

and in .h file declare it as,

```
 +(void)StartSpinner;
```

In other view controllers, import this class and call the method as follows:

```
[SpinnerController StartSpinner];
```

and similarly for other methods.

Answer (score 1):

U can do as follows,Write the following code in SharedController

```
- (UIAlertView *)createProgressViewToParentView:(UIView *)view withTitle:(NSString *)title
{
Alert_UserLocation = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[Alert_UserLocation show];

UIActivityIndicatorView *loaderView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 60, 25, 25)];
loaderView.tag = 3333;
loaderView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
loaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[Alert_UserLocation addSubview:loaderView];
[loaderView startAnimating];
[loaderView release];
return Alert_UserLocation;
}

- (void)hideProgressView:(UIAlertView *)inProgressView
{
if(Alert_UserLocation != nil)
{
    [Alert_UserLocation dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    Alert_UserLocation = nil;
}
}
```

And Import sharedController and create an object for sharedController in your View controller as follows

```
  sharedController = [SharedController sharedController];
  self.progressView = [sharedController createProgressViewToParentView:self.view withTitle:@"Loading..."];
```

Where ever u have to close use following code

```
    [sharedController hideProgressView:self.progressView];
```